# New hose bibb feels spongy

Tags: washer, bibb

Had two new Everbilt hose bibbs installed. When turning handle to shut off the water, the handle will turn back 1/16th of an inch counter-clockwise. It does it with every turn. It feels very spongy. However, water shuts off properly, no leaking. Is this normal? Both bibbs do the same thing.

Comment: Could just be because they're brand new.

Answer (score 0):

The supply line for the hose bibs may not be held firmly in place by pipe clamps within the wall. The spongy feel you're referring to is probably the supply line torquing when you shut it down.
This is usually more pronounced if the supply line is Pex rather than copper. Most bibs have a mounting flange with holes so you can secure the bib to the siding with wood screws. The installer may not have done this. If not, attaching these screws should solve your problem.
There are also external pipe clamps that you can find at your local plumbing store that you can attach externally to do the same thing.